# JavaScript join array into new array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

how do join the array and create new array?

```
var page_list = [ 'dkey', 'dvalue' ];
var json = '{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}';
var jp = JSON.parse(json);

for( var index in jp ) {
   var obj = jp[index]; 
   //page_list.concat( ['test1','value2'] );
}

//expecting output
[ [ 'dkey', 'dvalue' ], [ 'key1', 'value1'], ['key2','value2'], ['key3','value3'] ]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zerolfc/zjgx2pcj/1/

Can someone give me a solution, on how do I achieve the expecting output?

Comment: `jp` is not an array. `jp` is an object with attributes `key1`, `key2` and `key3`. So `jp[index]` has no meaning.

Comment: @Blip `jp[index]` works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var page_list = [ 'dkey', 'dvalue' ];
var arr = []; //Create new array
arr.push(page_list); //Push page_list

var json = '{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}';
var jp = JSON.parse(json);
for( var key in jp ) {
   arr.push([key, jp[key]]); //Push key, value 
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(arr))
//outputs
//[["dkey","dvalue"],["key1","value1"],["key2","value2"],["key3","value3"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.push()` and remove the `obj`:

```
$(function() {
    var array = [];
    var page_list = [ 'dkey', 'dvalue' ];
    var new_arr = '{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}';

    var jp = JSON.parse(new_arr);
    array.push( page_list );
    for( var index in jp ) {
        array.push( [index, jp[index]] );
    }
    console.log ( array );
});
```

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/zjgx2pcj/6/**

Comment: Doesn't outputs the expected result.

Comment: `var arr = [];
arr.push(page_list);` Repeating the comment `Doesn't outputs the expected result`

Comment: Yes it looks good now you accept my original comment `Doesn't outputs the expected result`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```js
var page_list = [ 'dkey', 'dvalue' ];
var json = '{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}';
var jp = JSON.parse(json);

// Map all values from `jp` into an array.
var arr = Object.keys(jp).map(function (key) {return [key, jp[key]]});
// Add `page_list` as first item of the array.
arr.unshift(page_list);

console.log(arr);
alert(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

`Object.keys(jp)` gets an array of keys from `jp` (So, `['key1', 'key2', 'key3']`).

Then, `.map` iterates over that result, where `[key, jp[key]` is returned for each key, which results in `['key1', 'value1']` etc.
Finally, `page_list` is added at the front of `arr`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:-

```
$(function() {

  var array = [];
  var page_list = [ 'dkey', 'dvalue' ];

  var new_arr = '{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}';

  var jp = JSON.parse(new_arr);
  parentArr = [];

  for( var index in jp ) {
      var obj = jp[index];
      parentArr.push([index, obj]);
  }
  parentArr.push(page_list);
  console.log(parentArr);

 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zjgx2pcj/4/

Comment: Why did you add `$(function(){ });` ?

Comment: @Cerbrus Just defining it all in a scope. Its not necessary you can remove it .

Comment: For answers on SO, I'd advice against adding extra's like that.